# style width on ::before div

Tags: html, css

I need some help with styling my headers. I had a question about css counter-increment here [css counter-increment unwanted reset when skipping :before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562639/css-counter-increment-unwanted-reset-when-skipping-before) and I got the counter to work, now my problem is the styling, I would like for it to be like this.

1.a Header 1 
10.a Header 2

```css
div.first:before
{
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    content: '1.a.\00a0';
}
div.second:before
{
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    content: '10.a.\00a0';
}

div.first {  
}
div.second {
}

h4.counter {
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    <h4 class="counter">foo</h4>
</div>

<div class="second">
    <h4 class="counter">foo</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Sanna Widell, try out adding style to `h4` tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h` elements are block level elements, therefore they cover 100% width and clear both sides.

You will need to change the display from `block` to `inline` and it will then line up.

Example:

```css
div.first:before
{
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    content: '1.a.\00a0';
}
div.second:before
{
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    content: '10.a.\00a0';
}

div.first {  
}
div.second {
}

h4.counter {
    display:inline
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    <h4 class="counter">foo</h4>
</div>

<div class="second">
    <h4 class="counter">foo</h4>
</div>
```

So this previous answer for an example of text which is aligned:[Align list items with custom CSS content before bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246689/align-list-items-with-custom-css-content-before-bullets/27246791#27246791)

Comment: That works good! But when I have more than one line I would like to have indentation on the other lines (except the first). Would that be possible? So the text on the second line starts at the same point as the text on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/spjf67ew/)**

**CSS:**

```
div.first:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content:'1.a.\00a0';
}
div.second:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content:'10.a.\00a0';
}
div.first, div.second {
    display: block;
}
h4.counter {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and small class you can add to your CSS file:

```
h4.counter{
    margin : -1.5% 0 0 3%;
    /*below seems to be hard-codednot so useful still can checkout:*/
    /*margin: -20px 0 0 35px;*/
}
```

And it will work as you wanted it to be.
[image]
[image]

Comment: hey @Sanna Widell, Is this helpful solution?

Comment: Hello @Victor, I have tried that before, but I want the text in the header to float after the counter.

Comment: what is the Header, in above example?

Comment: In my example "foo" is the text, and i would like i to look something like @Stewartside posted, but with som modification. I would like the second row (if the text takes multiple rows) to have indentation so it starts at the same point at the first line does.

Comment: have you really checked my code? bcuz, it gives headers with exact same indentation together, even in multiline text

Comment: Yes, I know, but the first letter when its 1.a starts at the same point at the first letter if i have 10.a. And i would like to have the same amout of space between them. But thanks for the help!

Comment: the out put image i'hv added; is it matches to your requirement?

Comment: Added a new image of how i would like it to look :)

Comment: this is how it worked at ur side? unbelievable! k fine, m not able crack it :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72574/discussion-between-sanna-widell-and-victor).